# Gradle: error: package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core does not exist

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, universal-image-loader

I am actually using using the universal image editor in my project and i included the jar file but i am getting error

Gradle: error: package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core does not exist
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class ImageLoader
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable ImageLoader
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable context
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable ImageLoaderConfiguration

http://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info

and i am using the new ide android-studio by any chance is that the cause of my problems

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put the library? Add it to the folder "libs"

Comment: i added the jar file to libs folder . Still it didn't work .Have u worked with this android studio did it work

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library/16628496#16628496), these are the steps I did:

Put the jar file (in my case, 'something.jar') into the libs folder of your project
Right click it and select Add as library
Type this in the dependencies part of build.gradle file: `compile files('libs/something.jar')`
Do a clean build. It can be done inside the android studio, but I also ran the gradlew.bat included inside the project folder
Now, the project should be built and run just fine.